# Rails routes direct index action to show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

So I created some rspec_scaffold for an Exercise model and added "map.resource :exercises" to my routes file and I was surprised when the "/exercises" url rendered the show action.  What the heck? Why doesn't that render the index action?

rake routes

```
new_exercises GET    /exercises/new(.:format)                           {:controller=>"exercises", :action=>"new"}
                edit_exercises GET    /exercises/edit(.:format)                          {:controller=>"exercises", :action=>"edit"}
                     exercises GET    /exercises(.:format)                               {:controller=>"exercises", :action=>"show"}
                               PUT    /exercises(.:format)                               {:controller=>"exercises", :action=>"update"}
                               DELETE /exercises(.:format)                               {:controller=>"exercises", :action=>"destroy"}
                               POST   /exercises(.:format)                               {:controller=>"exercises", :action=>"create"}
```

Comment: It has something todo with running the rspec_model or rspec_scaffold generator :/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You set up a singular route when you used the word `resource`. Use this instead.

```
map.resources :exercises
```

Comment: You sir, are a god. I've spent the last hour looking for engines over-riding routes. Little did I know I was missing an `s`